# setContentOffset to UIImage loaction in scrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have programmatically added images in imageViews to a parent scrollView in a for loop for 5 objects in an array.  Each imageView was given a TapGestureRecognizer so I can tap on them and they will call a function.
I want the function to setContentOffset in the scrollView to the location at the x value center of the tapped image.  I am not sure how to pull the CGPoint from the tapped imageView.  Any help would be great.
Here is what I have so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /*for (index, element) in list.enumerated()*/
    for (index, element) in cardsInHand.enumerated() {
        let img = UIImage(named: "\(element)")
        let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)
        imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        handScrollView.addSubview(imgView)

        //add tap gesture recognizer
        let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.cardTapped))
        imgView .addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)

        imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 5 + (5 + WIDTH) * CGFloat(index), y:  5, width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT)
    }


//test at card tapped function
func cardTapped(){
    handScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: WIDTH, y: 0), animated: true)
}
```

So far it just sets the offset on the scrollView to WIDTH (which is 110) no matter which card is tapped, because I don't know how to reference the imgView tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the index of `imageView` set the `tag` of that `imageView` inside your loop and then simply pass the reference of `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your method `cardTapped`.

```
for (index, element) in cardsInHand.enumerated() {
    let img = UIImage(named: "\(element)")
    let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)
    imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    handScrollView.addSubview(imgView)

    //add tap gesture recognizer
    let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.cardTapped))
    imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)

    //Set tag of imageView
    imgView.tag = index

    imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 5 + (5 + WIDTH) * CGFloat(index), y:  5, width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT)
}    

//Now pass tapGesture reference in your method like this
func cardTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) { 
    if let index = gesture.view?.tag {
        handScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index) * WIDTH, y: 0), animated: true) 
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works like a charm.

Comment: @Bezz Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.cardTapped))
```

to

```
let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.cardTapped(_:)))
```

This will allow you to pass the tap gesture as a parameter to your function and then you can access the view it was applied on-

```
func cardTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.view?.center)
}
```